# The buildcontext stopped working in the flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Everything worked fine except now I noticed the Buildcontext in Navigator.push appears pink in color and navigator push is not working. The buildcontext in all other pages work fine. What is causing this, only on two pages?

```
 Navigator.push(context/*this context appears in pink color*/
, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));
```

This is the homepage where the navigator for create account page is created.

```
 createUserInFirestore() async {
    // 1) check if user exists in users collection in database (according to their id)
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(user.id).get();
    // 2) if the user doesn't exist, then we want to take them to the create account page
    if (!doc.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(context , MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));

      // 3) get username from create account, use it to make new user document in users collection
      usersRef.document(user.id).setData({
        "id": user.id,
        "username": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
      // make new user their own follower (to include their posts in their timeline)
      await followersRef
          .document(user.id)
          .collection('userFollowers')
          .document(user.id)
          .setData({});
      doc = await usersRef.document(user.id).get();
    }
    currentUser = User.fromDocument(doc);
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  login() {
    googleSignIn.signIn();
  }
  logout() {
    googleSignIn.signOut();
  }
  onPageChanged(int pageIndex) {
    setState(() {
      this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    });
  }
  onTap(int pageIndex) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      pageIndex,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }
  Scaffold buildAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Timeline(currentUser: currentUser),
          Shop(),
          Designer(),
          Live(),
          ActivityFeed(),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTap,
        color: kSecondaryColor,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        backgroundColor:Colors.black38,
        animationCurve: Curves.elasticInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 000),
        height: 50.0,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.weekend, size: 30, color: kIcon,),
          Icon(Icons.store, size: 30,color: kIcon,),
          Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.swatchbook, size: 30,color: kIcon,),
          Icon(Icons.play_arrow, size: 30,color: kIcon,),
          Icon(Icons.inbox, size: 30,color: kIcon,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold  buildUnAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors:[ kPrimaryColor,
              kSecondaryColor

            ],
          ),
        ) ,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('FASHOW',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "MajorMonoDisplay",
                fontSize: 90.0,
                color: Colors.white,),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: login,
              highlightColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              splashColor: Colors.deepPurple,

              child: Container(
                width: 260.0,
                height: 60.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/img/google.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                ),

              ),

            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );


  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth? buildAuthScreen() : buildUnAuthScreen();
```

This is create account page where the all the context appears pink.

```
 class _CreateAccountState extends State<CreateAccount> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username;

  submit() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      SnackBar snackbar = SnackBar(
        content: Text("Welcome $username!"),
      );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        Navigator.pop(context, username);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: header(context,
          titleText: "Set up your profile", removeBackButton: true),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Create a username",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        autovalidate: true,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) {
                            if (val.trim().length < 3 || val.isEmpty) {
                              return "Username too short";
                            } else if (val.trim().length > 12) {
                              return "Username too long";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                          onSaved: (val) => username = val,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: "Username",
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                            hintText: "Must be at least 3 characters",
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: submit,
                  child: Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: 350.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Submit",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
```

Comment: Does the app compile ? 
Any error messages thrown?
Hover over the `context ` to see hints about the details of issue.

Comment: can I you share the rest of the code on the navigator + any errors or warnings you get while compiling / running the app?

Comment: there are no error while compiling the app.The app builds and installs too.Ive edited my question with codes on both the pages where im getting the error.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the error but you can pass `context` to `submit(context)` in `onTap`

Comment: sorry it didnt solve